# Saml token expiry time

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have configured my web application using SAML to go through the SSO flow. Things are working fine. I wanted to update the token expiry time.
Can you let me know the best way to do it?

Tried using graph API to create policy i.e. tokenLifetimePolicies and then assign to the application created in Azure but looks like it is not working as expected.

Thanks,
Pratap